# Reading and Writing any file in C++

Tags: c++, pdf, file-io, diff

I have a program where I need to operate on different types of files.
I want the input and output files of the following program to be the same.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<fstream>
#include<sstream>

typedef unsigned char u8;

using namespace std;

char* readFileBytes(string name)
{
    ifstream fl(name);
    fl.seekg( 0, ios::end );
    size_t len = fl.tellg();
    char *ret = new char[len];
    fl.seekg(0, ios::beg); 
    fl.read(ret, len);
    fl.close();
    return ret;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    string name = "file.pdf";

    u8* file = (u8*) readFileBytes(name);

    // cout<<str<<endl;
    int len = 0; 
    while(file[len] != '\0')
        len++;
    cout<<"FILESIZE : "<<len<<endl;

 
    string filename = "file2.pdf";
    ofstream outfile(filename,ios::out | ios::binary);
    outfile.write((char*) file,len);        
    outfile.close();
    exit(0);
}
```

The difference between the output and input files is checked using `diff`

```
diff file.pdf file2.pdf
```

What should I do to make `file2.pdf` the same as `file.pdf`?

I have tried using `xxd` to change the binary into hexadecimal but the disadvantage is that the overall size doubles. So therefore I want to operate in binary only.

Comment: Not sure you should check for '\0' your binary file is not a string so null terminator doesnt apply here. i suggest reading the bytes into a std::vector and returning that from your function and using the size of the vector to write out the data

Comment: That also avoids memory leak :)

Comment: You could also use a `std::string` to store the whole file. [example](https://godbolt.org/z/3jjzssThb)

Answer (score 2):

```
size_t len = fl.tellg();
char *ret = new char[len];
```

In this manner the shown code determines the number of characters in the file. This is fine. The only problem with it is that after this number of characters is read, this very important information is completely forgotten and thrown away. This function returns only this `ret` pointer, and the actual number of characters in it is now an unsolvable mystery.

But then, `main()` attempts to solve this mystery as follows:

```
int len = 0; 
while(file[len] != '\0')
    len++;
```

This attempts to reverse-engineer the number of characters by looking for the first 0 byte in the buffer.

Which has absolutely nothing to do with anything. The first character in the file may be a 0 byte, so this will calculate that the file is empty, and not ten gigabytes in size.

Or the file can contain just a string "Hello world", which this `for` loop will happily blow past, then start rooting around in some random memory after this buffer, resulting in undefined behavior.

That's the fatal logical flaw in the shown code: the actual size of the file is thrown away, and instead reverse-engineered in a flawed way.

You will need to rework the code so that the number of characters in the file, the original `len`, is also returned to `main()`, and it uses that, instead of attempting to guess what it originally was.

P.S. `delete`-ing the `ret` buffer, after you're done with it, would also be a good idea too. An even better idea is to avoid using `new`, using `vector` instead, which will happily give you its `size()` any time you ask for it, and you won't have to worry about deleting the allocated memory.

Answer (score 0):

In order to correctly process *binary* data, the size must be stored and cannot be computed from a sentinel null byte, because null bytes can be legimate bytes in a binary file. So you should return the read lenght in addition to the buffer, or even better copy each buffer to the new file until you have exhausted the input file:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    constexpr size_t sz = 10240;           // size of buffer
    char buffer[sz];
    string name = "file.pdf";
    string filename = "file2.pdf";
    ifstream fl(name);
    ofstream outfile(filename,ios::out | ios::binary);
    int len = 0, buflen; 
    for (;;) {
        buflen = fl.read(buf, len);
        if (buflen == 0) break;      // reached EOF
        len += buflen;
        if (buflen != outfile.write(buf, buflen)) {
            // display an error message
            return 1;
        }
    }
    fl.close();
    outfile.close()
    cout<<"FILESIZE : "<<len<<endl;
    exit(0);
}
```